# Mapping depth pixels to colour pixels using pyrealsense2

Tags: python, computer-vision, intel

I have an Intel Realsense Depth Camera D415. I am trying to use this method of mapping the pixels from the **depth channel** to **colour channel**. I am using the Python API and apparently the `pyrealsense2.align()` method is very CPU intensive and it dramatically slows down my application. So, I was thinking maybe mapping **depth pixels** to **colour pixels** would allow me make things run faster. However, I ran into the following problem: when I try to map depth pixel **[200, 200]** to its corresponding colour pixel I get returned **[15294.3466796875, -113.68994140625]**. I doubt this is correct since my colour channel resolution is **1280x720** and my colour coordinates are clearly out of **[0, 1280]**, **[0, 720]**. The code ([link](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/pull/1118)) I am using is the following:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
pipe_profile = pipeline.start()
frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

# Intrinsics & Extrinsics
depth_intrin = depth_frame.profile.as_video_stream_profile().intrinsics
color_intrin = color_frame.profile.as_video_stream_profile().intrinsics
depth_to_color_extrin = depth_frame.profile.get_extrinsics_to(color_frame.profile)
color_to_depth_extrin = color_frame.profile.get_extrinsics_to(depth_frame.profile)

print "\n Depth intrinsics: " + str(depth_intrin)
print "\n Color intrinsics: " + str(color_intrin)
print "\n Depth to color extrinsics: " + str(depth_to_color_extrin)

# Depth scale - units of the values inside a depth frame, i.e how to convert the value to units of 1 meter
depth_sensor = pipe_profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor()
depth_scale = depth_sensor.get_depth_scale()
print depth_scale
# Map depth to color
depth_pixel = [200, 200]   # Random pixel
print "\n\t depth_pixel: " + str(depth_pixel)
depth_point = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(depth_intrin, depth_pixel, depth_scale)
color_point = rs.rs2_transform_point_to_point(depth_to_color_extrin, depth_point)
color_pixel = rs.rs2_project_point_to_pixel(color_intrin, color_point)
print "\n\t color_pixel: " + str(color_pixel)
pipeline.stop()
```

In addition, this is what gets printed:

```
 Depth intrinsics: width: 1280, height: 720, ppx: 644.664, ppy: 406.596, fx: 965.563, fy: 965.563, model: Brown Conrady, coeffs: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

 Color intrinsics: width: 640, height: 480, ppx: 330.929, ppy: 233.255, fx: 610.102, fy: 609.615, model: Brown Conrady, coeffs: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

 Depth to color extrinsics: rotation: [0.99999, 0.00428028, 0.0010846, -0.00427981, 0.999991, -0.000430169, -0.00108643, 0.000425523, 0.999999]
translation: [0.0151529, -0.00012542, -0.000400548]
0.0010000000475

     depth_pixel: [200, 200]

     color_pixel: [15294.3466796875, -113.68994140625]
```

**1.Is anyone aware of a workaround in this case?**

**2.Are there any other transformations I need to carry out?** 
Any help/guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: hi @ASML, take a look at this issue from Intel [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/2204).

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. The output pixel is a ridiculous one, with extremely high `x` value -like yours, 15294, which shouldn't be the case-. The linked conversation is not solving the issue either.

Comment: Hi @Schütze, are you still having the issue with the latest version of librealsense2?

Comment: @VladSirbu I had the problem but I fixed it by re-calibrating it.